# How to hide scroll bar in react app with allowing scrolling?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, chakra-ui

I am trying to hide scrollbar in my react app but not being able to achieve it. I tried using `::-webkit-scrollbar` with width as 0 or display as none but not able to achieve the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from [W3 Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_hide_scrollbars.asp)

```css
/* Hide scrollbar for Chrome, Safari and Opera */
.example::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

/* Hide scrollbar for IE, Edge and Firefox */
.example {
  -ms-overflow-style: none;  /* IE and Edge */
  scrollbar-width: none;  /* Firefox */
}
```